# Querying objects from static List causing spikes on cpu usage on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, collections

We have a feature similar to the Related questions on SO where we show related records when viewing a given record. The related records were being retrieved by calling the db every time the page was loaded. To reduce the load on the db, I created a static List of these records which I load on Application_Start and am now using Linq query to query this List.

For the most part this seems to work fine. The load on the db has reduced and the Sql profiler shows there are no more related records query. I had pushed this change last night and this morning I found the IIS worker process to be with CPU at 100% and the website unresponsive. I switched back to the old code (where I query db) and things were fine on the web server but db load increased. So I switched to the new code again and have been looking at the cpu load on the web server. This is what I noticed.

When using the old code which queries the db, the cpu usage of the IIS Worker process is negligible and there are hardly any variations (straight line seen in the performance tab of task manager) However, when using the new code which creates and queries the static List, I see spikes in the cpu usage of the IIS worker process. Mostly it is between 1 and 5 % but every now and then it spikes over that and the max I have seen is 40% since I started observing. I am wondering why this is happening and whether under heavy load, this could have resulted in the worker process crashing?

Here is some of the code which is querying the static List

```
    if (validSearchLatLong && (usePincodeLatLong || distanceFilterLimit != distanceLimit))
        {
            filteredRecords = StaticRecords.Where(job => LatLongDistance(centerLatitude, centerLongitude, job.lat, job.lon) <= distanceFilterLimit || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PreferredJobCity) ? job.city == this.PreferredJobCity : false)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            filteredRecords = StaticRecords.Where(job => (this.PreferredJobCity != "" ? job.city == this.PreferredJobCity : (this.City != "" ? job.city == this.city : (state != "" ? job.state.Trim() == state.Trim() : false)))).ToList();
        }

        if (RecordsearchFilter.JobCategories.Count > 0 && RecordsearchFilter.EnableFilter)
        {
            filteredRecords = filteredRecords.Where(job => this.RecordsearchFilter.JobCategories.Contains(job.JobCategoryClass)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            filteredRecords = filteredRecords.Where(job => MatchJobCategories(job.JobCategory, (short)this.jobCategory.SqlId) > 0).ToList();
        }
```

List supports multiple concurrent readers, so StaticRecords should not be the blocking factor. And after that I am creating filteredRecords which is a new filtered List which should be independent of other threads.

What could be the possible reasons for spikes in CPU and could it have resulted in the earlier crash of the IIS worker process?

============EDIT==============

I now know that the crash was not caused due to this code, but another bug. The static List approach has been stable and seems to have worked well to achieve its purpose.

But my question still remains, why the spikes in CPU?

When I say

> List supports multiple concurrent readers, so StaticRecords should not
>   be the blocking factor. And after that I am creating filteredRecords
>   which is a new filtered List which should be independent of other
>   threads.

am I wrong?

Comment: Have you turned on Tracing to view the time taking for the method calls?

Comment: how big is staticrecords? Are you seeing pagefaults during the spikes? StaticRecords uses a List<T>?

Comment: @rene Yes StaticRecords uses a List<T>. It has about 35000 records. By pagefaults if you mean errors in the asp.net pages, then no, I haven't seen any yet.

Comment: @sassyboy with pagefaults I mean memory pagefaults, ie when the memory manager in the OS has to fetch memory blocks from the disk. Although it is retired content, still usefull: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647791.aspx

Comment: Years later... having same issue. Linq executes fast but CPU way out of whack

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server is generally very efficient at querying, especially when you have correctly optimized indexes.

Your new `StaticRecords` approach requires an in-memory scan through all the items, performing the Where predicate for each. This is likely the cause for your increased CPU usage, especially if there is many items in `StaticRecords`. Try attaching a profiler and see for yourself. In general, I would expect this kind of filtering to perform orders of magnitude better when running on the SQL Server vs the in-memory filtering.

Comment: Well, the increase in CPU usage on the webserver is expected and is alright as long as it is consistent (mostly between 1 and 5%). It is the spikes in usage that I am concerned about (when it reaches 40%). Why do I see sudden spikes?  As for using Sql server, well the in-memory approach is to reduce the load on Sql server. The particular query in question is optimized and all the necessary indexes are in place. I am certain there must be further optimizations possible at db end, but cannot have the site down while we come up with a solution. This is more like a quick fix

Comment: Have you considered caching the results ? Spikes might have such a simple cause as a few concurrent request all hitting that code.

Answer (score 1):

The performance issues are probably due to scanning the `List` in `StaticRecords`.

Reading the data into memory once is fine, but it looks like you need a more efficient data structure in order to query it effectively. You also might want to revisit the idea of using LINQ to do the query.

As far as what caused your crash and 100% CPU spikes, I don't see an obvious error in the code you posted.

Comment: What would you suggest to use instead of Linq? Apart from the above two filters there are many more filters. The approach is in such a way that the first filter reduces the list by a lot and then passes the filteredRecords to the next filter which then further reduces and again same thing for the few filters. Currently the staticList contains about 35000 objects and after the first filter, the result is around 5000 objects. The next filter is applied on 5000 objects instead of 35000. So it does work fine. I am worried about sudden spikes, what could be causing them and possibility of crash

Comment: Use LINQ - don't use it in Application_Start.  Instead, query your model when you need to, but cache your queries (make the cachekey a delimited list of the parameters, for example)